# Campo Nullable<DateTime> 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um campo da Model

```
[Column("sdt_dataPagamento")]
[Display(Name = "Dt. Pagamento")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? DataPagamento { get; set; }
```

Estou exibindo na View esse campo porém os valores `null` ficam como `01/01/0001`

Como já tentei solucionar esse problema.

```
@if (item.DataPagamento.HasValue)
{
    item.DataPagamento.Value.ToShortDateString();
    <span>teste</span>
}
```

O `teste` aparece mas a data não.

Se faço assim:

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataPagamento)
```

Aparece no formato `2016-04-12 (aaaa-mm-dd)`

Também tentei

```
@if(item.DataPagamento.Value.Year != 0001
@if(item.DataPagamento != null)
@if(item.DataPagamento != DateTime.MinValue)
//entre outras tentativas
```

**Desejo exibir apenas a Data dd/mm/aaaa**

Não gostaria de modificar os atributos da model pois poderia apresentar erros em outras views, sei que não é o correto exibir model na view, deveria criar uma ViewModel, mas na prática acabo as vezes fazendo quando 'acho' que é simples.
Só modificaria a Model se realmente ela estiver errada e for a única forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou um `@` aqui:

```
@if (item.DataPagamento.HasValue)
{
    @item.DataPagamento.Value.ToShortDateString();
    <span>teste</span>
}
```

Comment: existe alguma forma melhor ou tenho que fazer esse if?

Comment: Se estiver usando C# 6 -> `item.DataPagamento?.ToShortDateString() ?? ""`. Se estiver usando uma versão anterior -> `item.DataPagamento.HasValue ? item.DataPagamento.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""`